# How do I return the right JSON data from a Rails controller to a jQuery autocomplete select box?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying really hard to implement jQuery UI's "combo box" example. I have set up a remote data source, and it returns the values I type in. However, it only works if I return an array of strings, like so:

```
render :text => Product.find_by_sql("select id, part_number from products where part_number like '#{params[:term]}%'").collect{|p| p.part_number}.to_json
```

What I really want to do, of course, is to have it *also* return the id of the AR object. Unfortunately, when I try to return them both in a subarray, I get a bunch of "undefined" values in my combo box.

Here is the "select" event which fires on my combo box:

```
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                    item: ui.item.option
                });
            },
```

I have been through the jQuery UI docs, and I can't figure out what this code actually does. Also, I can't figure out what the structure of the JSON I need to return should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an array of hashes, each of which has two attributes - id and label.

I've used this with success:

```
collect{|p| {:label=>p.name, :id=>p.id}}.to_json
```

(I think you'd want to call part_number instead of name on your object, but that's the format)

Separately, I think your code is open to sql injection, you should use the "like ?" syntax.

```
Product.where( "part_number like ?", "#{params[:term]}%" )
```

There's also this gem, which I haven't used but should work:

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the rails portion of what you're working on, but I do know that the format the autocomplete  widget expects is as follows:

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, **with either a label or value
>   property or both**.

What the above means is that if you don't return a simple `Array` of strings, you must have an array of objects that includes *at least* a label or value property (the objects in the array can contain other things, the widget does not care). For example, the following will work just fine (and you can access the `id` property in event handlers (e.g. `ui.item.id`)

```
[{ label: 'Google', id: '1234' }, { label: 'Yahoo', id: '2345' }, ... ];
```

---

Concerning your second question:

> I have been through the jQuery UI docs, and I can't figure out what this code actually does.

The piece of code in question is supposed to modify the underlying `select` element of the combobox and set the appropriate `option` as selected. If you're using a remote data source, you probably can do without this entirely.